# Loop thumbnails and display

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to loop images from a thumbnails folder (with already presized thumbnails) and link them to their respective full size images. The names will match exactly so I should be able to do this with one loop.

The question is do I need to open both directories before I can start looping through them? In my example, I'm pulling from the Montague Vacations folder which has both the thumbs and full size folders.

```
$files = array();
$dir = opendir('./assets/vacations/montague'); // open the cwd..also do an err chec

while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
    if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "index.php")){
            $files[] = $file; // put in array.
    }   
}

natsort($files); // sort.

$counter = 0;

// print.
foreach($files as $file) {
    $counter++;
    echo "<code>";
    print htmlentities("
    <li>
        <!--[if gte IE 9]><!--><a href='#pic-$counter'><!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><a href=/userfiles/images/portfolio/web-templates/big/fastedit.png' target='_blank'><![endif]-->
        <img src='%base_url%/assets/vacations/montague/thumb/$file alt='' />
        <span><b>Preview</b></span>
        </a>
        <div id='pic-$counter' class='overlay'>
        <img src='%base_url%/assets/vacations/montague/full/$file' alt='' />
        <div>
            <p>Picture caption here.</p>
        </div>
        <a href='#close' class='close' title='Close'>&times;</a>
    </div>
</li>
");
    echo ("<br />\n");
    echo ("<br />\n");
    echo "</code>";
}
```

Comment: Am I loosing it or does your code NOT load `$files` with anything at all?

Comment: @RiggsFolly lol no you're not, there's nothing to be printed based on that code alone, `$files`  should be empty. unless this is just a part (incomplete) of the code

Comment: Feel free to chip in anytime you like @Brian

Comment: no you don't need to open both, just get the one directory (full) if they use the same file name. just `opendir` + `readdir` on the full size, then use the file name inside the thumb (if they really use the same filename). as a sidenote, you could use a `file_exists` first before printing

Comment: @RiggsFolly - forgot to add the while loop that prefilters .png/jpeg files, sorry.

Comment: @Ghost - Would I just loop through the thumbs the same way? How would they be displayed?

Comment: @Brian you can just call them in a linear fashion as long as both full and thumb file names have the correct filename and path, under the same loop, as long as they exist, and have the same name

Comment: Works great. I'm having the main directory set to the thumbnails and just specified the directory /full for the fullsize images and by using the same names it finds them in a snap. Thanks.